# How to convert “ Sun May 31 23:59:00 EDT 2015” to 31/05/2015?

Tags: javascript

I have a value like the following Sun May 31 23:59:00 EDT 2015 and i want to convert this to 31/05/2015

How to convert this using javascript Date?

Comment: Everything you need to know about [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Answer could be possibly [Formatting Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/769678)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date("Sun May 31 23:59:00 EDT 2015");
var f_date = d.getDate();
var f_month = d.getMonth()+1;
var f_year = d.getFullYear();
new_string=f_date+"/"+f_month+"/"+f_year;
```

added 1 into month( as it starts from 0)
New_string is date in required format

Note- it will be given according to local timezone